# How to use Raspberry Pi 3 inbuilt bluetooth for serial communication with PC?

Tags: pi-3, serial, bluetooth

I want to send data from Raspberry Pi 3 having Raspian Jessie OS. I can pair with other bluetooth devices using the Bluetooth Icon on the task bar and also using `bluetoothctl`. I tried to connect to a HC06 but it says "No usable services on this device". I have no idea how to establish serial communication to send data wirelessly from RPi to PC's serial terminal.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can discover and pair with the HC-06 using the Bluetooth GUI, but after connecting it says there are no usable services. It's as though the Raspberry Pi doesn't have the Serial Profile setup, but I don't know how to add it!

Comment: Did you find a solution? @ChrisRoberts

Comment: Not yet, I'm afraid - but I haven't had a huge amount of time to spend on it, I'm afraid!